# How to align 1 and -1 in Linear equation?

Tags: overleaf

[image]

[image]

How to align 1 and -1 like the picture do?

I am trying to typeset the following equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}
\begin{document}
\systeme{x_1+2x_2-x_3=-1, 2x_1+2x_2+x_3=1, 3x_1+5x_2-2x_3=-1}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to use aray, which works like tabular but in math mode.  Use [r] columns for the units and [c] columns for the operators.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Instead of a screenshot, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

That way those trying to help can focus on the solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case.  A quick solution in this case that should work is to replace the `1` with `\hphantom{-}1`.

Comment: If you have version 0.33 or later of the systeme package then `\sysalign{r,r}` will right-align the RHS

Answer (score 3):

As @JohnKormylo has noted in a comment, you may achieve your formatting objective by employing an `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of next instruction
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt} % default: 5py
a) $\left\{ \ 
   \begin{array}{ rCrCr @{{}={}} r}
     x_1 & + & 2x_2 & - &  x_3 & -1 \\
    2x_1 & + & 2x_2 & + &  x_3 &  1 \\
    3x_1 & + & 5x_2 & - & 2x_3 & -1
   \end{array}
   \right.$
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why did you need to define the C column type. Wouldn't just using c have worked as well?

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg - The `c` column type won’t give us the right amount of spacing (medmuskip for binary operators such as `+` and `-`, thickmuskip for relational operators such as `=`). To see the difference between these two lengths, try typesetting `$0+0=0$` and look closely for the difference in space around `+` and around `=`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation of the `systeme` package is in French, so it's maybe difficult to understand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\sysalign{r,r}

\begin{document}

\systeme{x_1+2x_2-x_3=-1, 2x_1+2x_2+x_3=1, 3x_1+5x_2-2x_3=-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first `r` refers to ***r***ight alignment in the left-hand sides, the second one refers to ***r***ight alignment in the right-hand sides.

Comment: Wow. What systeme appears to do is fantastic. I don't read French, but I can read the examples.

Comment: @JeffreyGoldberg For linear systems it is very handy and it can be coaxed to do even other things.